# Duda sobre moneda a usar al realizar pago a otro pais con mercado pago

Tags: mercadopago

En mi aplicación permito a mis vendedores vender en Argentina y Chile, mi duda es como hago para que un chileno le pague a un argentino? Que moneda uso en la aplicación? Esto hace el cambio de divisa automaticame y en caso de hacerlo, tiene algún costo? 
Donde puedo leer mas al respecto?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar paypal si los fees te lo permiten

Comment: La idea es usar el api de mercado pago por el momento

Answer (score 1):

Por lo pronto lo que puedes hacer es pagar con la tarjeta de otro país en un sitio que implementa mercado pago, si bien recuerdo las solucione de checkout aún no operan de manera cross-país sino que es necesario usar las credenciales de cada país y debe haber una instancia de la aplicación por país ya que existen restricciones y normativas distintas, como pagos en cuotas, bancos, tasas de interesa, información mínima necesaria etc, ademas de que no todas las funcionalidades estan disponibles en todos los paises o pueden funcionar de manera distinta.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas

Entiendo que si usas paypal como intermediario entre empresas para recibir el pago la empresa receptora recibirá la pago en su moneda local por ejemplo:

- Argentina vende N producto = 50 pesos argentinos 
  Chile compra  N producto = en su moneda al cambio equivalente a los 50 pesos argentinos.
- La api de paypal te permite cobrar en diferentes países al currency de tu pais pero ellos te cargan un % por transacciones.

Ese es el caso que tienes que estudiar mas a fondo, espero poder ayudarte con esta respuesta

Comment: Seria bueno puedas añadir una fuente a tu respuesta, ya que si bien recuerdo PayPal opera únicamente en dólares en algunos países de latinoamérica.

Comment: Claro Puedes verificarlo aqui [https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_display-xborder-fees-outside]  es cierto que las transacciones son en dolares pero no afecta tu flujo ya que tu precio sera el mismo en dolares

Comment: Buen aporte , lo que entiendo es que recaudas en PayPal y pagas una comisión de > 5% PayPal lo guarda en dólares en tu cuenta y luego debes hacer un retiro en tu país pagando otro monto por la conversión, no sé si es tan viable perder por doble conversión además de la alta comisión, si el negocio lo permite es una buena opción.